# Selenium Select Child with Several Children all Named the Same Thing

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

New to Selenium and web stuff in general and I am running into an element not found problem trying to find and element with XPath.

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`

I've been trying to figure it for a bit, but i cant seem to puzzle it out. Apologize in advance if I've missed something obvious. But if it is a simple google to figure out, i haven't come across the term yet.

When I look with inspect element I get the following two options for the XPath

```
//*[@id='fundamental-analysis-summary-container']/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div
```

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[10]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div
```

There are four different children i want to grab, and they are all variations of these values with li[1], li[2], li[3], and li[4]

The html line i am trying to extract in particular is componentValue from the following.

```html
<div class="rating-text" ng-bind="data.componentValue">84</div>
```

and the surrounding html looks something like

```html
<div id="foo-analysis-summary-container" class="foo-analysis-summary" data="fooAnalysis">
    <!----><ul class="analysis-items" ng-if="hasData == true">
        <li class="foo-analysis-item summary" title="Valuation" scs-url="fooData.scsUrl" category="Valuation" low-label="Overvalued" high-label="Undervalued" data="fooData.valuation">
    <!----><div class="fas-title" ng-if="mode == 'summary'">
        <div class="tooltip-overlay-container" label="Valuation" container-id="foo-analysis-summary-container" content="How much item is worth">
  <!---->
  <!----><a class="tooltip-label" ng-if="title == undefined &amp;&amp; label != undefined" title="Valuation" ng-click="onClick()" ng-bind="label">Valuation</a><!---->

  <div class="overlay-container" ng-class="{'isVisible': isVisible}" ng-style="{'top': overlayTop, 'left': overlayLeft, 'width': width }" style="width: 270px;">
    <div class="tooltip-pointer down-pointer ng-hide" ng-show="isUp == false" ng-style="{'left': arrowLeft}" aria-hidden="true"><div class="rsh_snapshot_sprite_img rsh_snapshot_sprite_pointer_up"></div></div>
    <div class="tooltip-overlay-content">
      <div class="rsh_snapshot_sprite_img rsh_snapshot_sprite_close_gray close-icon" ng-click="onClose()" role="button" tabindex="0"></div>
        <!----><div ng-if="label != undefined" class="tooltip-title" ng-bind="label">Valuation</div><!---->
        <!---->
        <!----><div ng-if="!hasTransclusion &amp;&amp; !contentHtml" class="tooltip-text">N/A</div><!---->

        <!---->
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip-pointer up-pointer ng-hide" ng-show="isUp == true" ng-style="{'left': arrowLeft}" aria-hidden="true"><div class="rsh_snapshot_sprite_img rsh_snapshot_sprite_pointer_up"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div><!---->
    <!---->
    <!----><div class="scale" ng-if="hasData == true">
        <div class="rating-cursor">
            <div class="rating-label" ng-style="{'left': 'calc(' + data.componentValue + '% - 10px)'}" style="left: calc(84% - 10px);">
                <div aria-atomic="true"><span class="screen-reader-only">current = </span><div class="rating-text" ng-bind="data.componentValue">84</div></div>
                <div class="triangle-cursor"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ruler">
            <div class="separator s1"></div>
            <div class="separator s2"></div>
            <div class="separator s3"></div>
            <div class="separator s4"></div>
            <div class="current-value" ng-style="{'width': data.componentValue + '%'}" style="width: 84%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fas-labels">
            <div aria-atomic="true"><div class="start-value-label" ng-bind="lowLabel">Overvalued</div><span class="screen-reader-only"> = 0</span></div>
            <div aria-atomic="true"><div class="end-value-label" ng-bind="highLabel">Undervalued</div><span class="screen-reader-only"> = 100</span></div>
        </div>
    </div><!---->

    <!-- Detail Metrics -->
    <!---->

    <!---->
</li>
    ... repeated three times with different values ...
</div>
```

The code i am trying to execute is the following.

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fundamental-analysis-summary-container']/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div")
```

I've gotten it to work with find_element_by_css_selector, but from my limited grasp of things I've googled, that doesn't work because of the li in this case and I have to use xpath. If it helps, the css selector is

```
li.foo-analysis-item:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)
```

or this

```
#foo-analysis-summary-container > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div.scale > div.rating-cursor > div > div:nth-child(1) > div
```

Comment: What is the error and what are you trying to do with the web element? Is selenium not finding the xpath or is selenium not interacting with the web element??

Comment: The message it gives is
```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:```
@AaronCloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your element text taking in account `li` you can use the following css selector:

```
el_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".foo-analysis-item.summary:nth-of-type(1) .rating-text").text
```

Or one of these xpaths:

```
el_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[1]//div[@class='rating-text']").text

el_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[1]//div[@ng-bind='data.componentValue']").text
```

Comment: I tried all of these and at first it didnt work. But then i had the bright idea to scroll down until the text was visible on the screen, and what do you know it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Falderol It could be because your not allowing the page to load. Try adding some browser.implictywaits or time.sleep into your code to slow it down. If selenium doesn't see if right away it will usually throw that kind of error.